# How to not focus when using Ajax Timer Control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

when i using ajax control but control tick every 1 secound and when i click other control the control not focus in selection my control when timer tick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That particular timer must be placed inside the update panel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
   </asp:Timer>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it:

http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/05/bug_bash_enablingdisabling_the.html

This is how I approached it (note that the server-side tags for Timer1 and the "txtSymbol" textbox are approached differently):

```
<asp:Content ID="HeadContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Website1/Styles/lessantique.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoad(sender, args){
            //  fetch the timer components
            var timer = $find('<%= this.Timer1.ClientID %>');

            //  fetch the INPUT element
            var textbox = $get('Content1_txtSymbol');
            $addHandler(textbox, 'focus', Function.createDelegate(this, function(){
                //   disable the Timer so we don't refresh the page
                //   while the user is entering the data
                timer._update(false, timer.get_interval()); 
            }));
            $addHandler(textbox, 'blur', Function.createDelegate(this, function(){
            //   re-enable the Timer
            timer._update(true, timer.get_interval()); 
            }));                
        } 
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

regarding the server side code for the timer listed in the previous response, that approach did not work for me since I have more than one update panel, where the text box is not in the same panel that uses the timer. In that case I followed the advice at http://forums.asp.net/t/1632054.aspx/1, where a new panel is implemented, as such:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel3" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" >
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Timer runat="server" id="Timer1" Enabled="true"  
       Interval="2000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" />
   </ContentTemplate>            
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Despite the above not producing errors, the results were still unsatisfactory, therefore the client-side approach.